# Why do we count in two ways?

Tags: combinatorics, soft-question

To prove combinatorial identities, I've always been taught to count in two ways. Why do we do this, rather than just use algebraic manipulations to go from one side to the other?

Comment: Could you give an example of what you mean?

Comment: The first way is a combinatorial proof, which can give some insight about *why* the two sides are equal.  The second way is an algebraic proof, which doesn't.  Induction is similar; it gives a proof "by magic" with little insight.

Comment: Can you derive all combinatorial identities with algebraic manipulations?  I don't know how to prove the identity $bk=vr$ for a balanced incomplete block design just using algebra, for example.  It's possible that it can be done, but I've never seen it (and I'm not about to try).  I'm also not sure if there is a purely algebraic argument to prove the relation $(v-k-1)\mu=k(k-\lambda-1)$ for strongly regular graphs.

Answer (score 4):

Because it is fun. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 0):

**Short Version.**

Because the most interesting problems regarding counting are insanely difficult to solve using algebraic tools only. And sometimes, even with algebra as an aid they are still  difficult.

**Long Version**

Try to count the following using only algebra. $\underline{\text{No cheating, don't look it up.}}$

Let $(a,b) \in \mathbb{Z_+}^2$, that is $(a,b)$ is a lattice point on the first quadrant including both axis. We define a step by moving one unit north, east, south, or west.

Restrict any path to $(a,b)$ to the first quadrant only. In how many ways can you get to $(a,b)$ using $a+b+6$ steps as defined above?

Comment: I just realized, your question says "To prove combinatorial identities," in my response I assumed the identities are unknown. Sorry. I hope it at least helps you to understand that to come up with the identities in the first place algebra is ill-suited to help.